# Non-blocking Request-Reply scheme (ZeroMQ)

Tags: c, zeromq

I am exchanging messages between two machines using ZeroMQ sockets, in a Request-Reply scheme.  This exchange is done with a C program, with some other functionalities.

In the case where the responder machine is down, the requester waits indefinitely for a message, blocking the rest of the program's functionalities. This is not what I want.

I've tried using:

```
zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 256, ZMQ_DONTWAIT);
```

but the requester returns right away, because there is no message in its queue (obviously).

Is there any way to have a non-blocking request-reply scheme in ZeroMQ? Something like: "if the message was not received within 1 second, return".

Answer (score 1):

The function: `select()` has a 'timeout' parameter that you can set to 1 second.  Then `select()` returns when one of the selected file descriptors needs servicing -OR- when 1 second has elapsed.  Suggest reading the MAN page for `select()` for the details

Comment: there is no select() in the C API. I suppose you're talking about zmq_poll(), which does have a timeout argument. However, when I test the code: 
`while (1) {
        zmq_pollitem_t items [] = {{ requester, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 }};
        zmq_poll (items, 1, 1);

        if (items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
            int size = zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 4, 0);
        }
    }`
no message is received, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: actually, `select()` is part of the C API.   [select MAN page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)